# Bundler::GemNotFound when executing delayed job stop during cap deploy

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano, delayed-job, rbenv

I'm doing some work with an old code base that was running Ruby 1.9.3 and Rails 3.2.3. However, I had to update to Ruby 2 (I chose 2.1.5, because I've used it in the past) to fix an SSL error that arose when using the PayPal API (my task was to implement PayPal for credit card processing). This caused an error with the asset pipeline, and after some investigation I discovered that Rails 3.2.3 didn't support Ruby 2.1.5, so I had to upgrade to Rails 3.2.19.

Everything was working fine on my local machine. When it came time to deploy, I installed rbenv on the server (it didn't have RVM or rbenv) and installed Ruby 2.1.5.

Now, the deploy script gets past bundle install, but when it tries to execute `cd /var/www/cappwww/current && RAILS_ENV=production script/delayed_job stop`, it chokes and says `Could not find *** in any of the sources (Bundler::GemNotFound)`.

"***" is just a placeholder; this happened first with i18n, then multi_json. I manually changed the requested versions of these gems and ran `bundle update`, and it seemed to work. However, it is now requesting activesupport 3.2.3, and I can't force it to use that because Rails 3.2.19 requires activesupport 3.2.19.

As far as I can tell, this isn't an issue of delayed_job actually requiring these gems, because 1) they would be installed during bundle install, or bundle install would complain if there was an unresolvable dependency, and 2) delayed_job requires activesupport >= 3 according to rubygems, so 3.2.19 should do just fine.

It seems that for some reason, the delayed_job script is looking for a very specific gemset, specifically the old gemset. However, I have no idea what could be causing it to do that.

My Gemfile is

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'

gem 'rake', '10.1.1'
gem 'rmagick'
gem 'rails', '3.2.19'
gem 'devise', '2.0'
gem 'haml', '3.1.4'
gem 'sass', '3.2.3'
gem 'formtastic', '2.1.0.rc'
gem 'cocaine', '0.3.2'

# Bundle edge Rails instead:
# gem 'rails', :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git'

#gem 'mysql2', '0.2.6'
gem 'mysql2', '0.3.11'
#gem 'less', '~> 2.0.8'
gem 'less', '~> 2.2.1'
gem 'tinymce-rails', '3.5.8'
gem 'will_paginate', '3.0.3'
gem 'country_select', '1.0.1'
gem 'paypal-sdk-rest'

# Use unicorn as the web server
gem 'unicorn'
gem 'jquery-rails', '2.1.4'
gem 'paperclip', '3.2.1'
gem 'feedzirra', '0.0.24'
gem 'delayed_job', '4.1.0'
gem 'delayed_job_active_record', '4.1.0'
gem 'daemons', '1.1.9'

gem 'therubyracer', '0.12.0'

# To use debugger (ruby-debug for Ruby 1.8.7+, ruby-debug19 for Ruby 1.9.2+)
# gem 'ruby-debug'
# gem 'ruby-debug19'

# Bundle the extra gems:
# gem 'bj'
# gem 'nokogiri'
# gem 'sqlite3-ruby', :require => 'sqlite3'
# gem 'aws-s3', :require => 'aws/s3'

gem 'rsolr', '1.0.7'
gem 'sunspot', '1.3.3'
gem 'sunspot_solr', '1.3.3'
gem 'sunspot_rails', '1.3.3'
gem 'hpricot', '0.8.6'

gem 'roadie', '2.3.4'


group :assets do
    gem 'sass-rails'
    gem 'uglifier'
end

# Bundle gems for the local environment. Make sure to
# put test-only gems in this group so their generators
# and rake tasks are available in development mode:
group :development, :test do
    # Deploy with Capistrano
    gem 'capistrano', '2.13.5'
    gem 'capistrano-rbenv'
    gem 'rspec-rails', '~> 2.6'
    gem 'machinist', '2.0'
    gem 'faker', '1.0.1'
    gem 'syntax', '1.0.0'
    gem 'progress_bar', '0.4.0'
end

group :development do
    gem 'active_record_query_trace', '1.1'
end
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, as I'm in pretty far over my head.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I figured it out. The `RAILS_ENV=production script/delayed_job stop` command was executing in the `current` folder, which is the previous release. Since I was using rbenv to force Ruby 2.1.5, the gems for the previous release had not been installed for the current version of Ruby, which is why delayed_job was complaining. Running `bundle install` in the `current` directory fixed the issue.